# Android PopUpWindow

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0, popupwindow

I have an app that has one Activity which creates a Surface View and inside the surface view places an OpenGL renderer. I am handling object picking inside the OpenGL renderer. What I want to do is when a user selects a particular object display a block of text and an image which I have stored in file. It seems as though Android's PopupWindow class would do this just fine. Would I be able to overlay the popup over the OpenGL Renderer? Or am I approaching this all backwards?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Well, my friend I had the same problem with you. I am going to explain what I did and I think it suits your problem.

I have a renderer where I display a mesh. The user can place comments on the mesh. I also do ray-picking as you do. When the user clicks on a comment, a Pop-Up window is displayed.

Essentially, what you need to do, is to call a method in your renderer which will run the Pop-Up in the UI thread. (OpenGl runs on its own thread).

To be more specific, you have to send a message to a Handler which will display the popup

**YourRenderer.java**

```
@Override
public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {
    .... code that displays the mesh ...

    if(userRequestedPopup) {
        Message message = new Message();
        message.what = DialogHandler.OPEN_ANNOTATION;

        // Here you can create a Bundle in order to pass more data inside the Message

        dialogHanlder.sendMessage(message);

        userRequestedPopup = false;
    }
....
}
```

**YourGLSurfaceView.java**  here you should create the Handler

```
public class DialogHandler extends Handler {
    ... other constants ...
    public static final int OPEN_ANNOTATION = 2;
    ...

    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        if (msg.what == OPEN_ANNOTATION) {
            new YourPopup(context, msg);
        } 
    }
}
```

Before creating the popup, you should design your own layout in xml (or create it programmatically if you want). In order to understand the code, I should mention that I call my layout `popup_layout`. 
Moreover you should add to the glsurfaceview's layout an empty layout (which should FILL the PARENT layout in both width and height), let's say a LinearLayout, which will hold your popup. I call it `popupHolder`

**YourPopup.java**

```
public Popup(Context context, Message message) {
    this.context = context;
    Activity parent = (Activity) context;

    // here you can have the instance of the holder from glSurfaceView
    LinearLayout parentLayout = (LinearLayout) parent.findViewById(R.id.popupHolder);

    // inflate your custom popup layout or create it dynamically 
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.popup_layout, null);

    // Now you should create a PopupWindow
    PopupWindow popupWindow = new PopupWindow(view, 
               LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,  
               LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    // you can change the offset values or the Gravity. This will diaply the popup in the center
    // of your glSurfaceView
    popupWindow.showAtLocation(parentLayout, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
}
```

I think this is what you need, because this solution works fine for me.

Hope I helped...

Answer (score 1):

Create a XML for your pop-up Window and then use this code in your Java file:

```
public void popupWindow() {
    PopupWindow pw;
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) MainActivity.this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.popup_window, (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.txtPusdNotR));

    pw = new PopupWindow(layout, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, true);
    pw.showAtLocation(layout, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);

    // Get your Buttons and other tags here

}
```